# Unexpected value for 'this' in express.js instantiated controllers

Tags: node.js, express, prototype, this, undefined

'this' does not appear to refer to the instantiated budget controller object. Instead it seems to refer to the global object. Does anyone know why this is?

I've defined a budget model. Injected into the controller and I'm attempting to simply generate a random 6 char string when I hit /budgets in my app. Instead this.DEFAULT_SLUG_LENGTH is undefined and I can't figure out why.

This is a dumbed down test case illustrating the issue with 'this'. I have a similar problem when referencing the injected this.budget within another function to query the db based on the slug value.

```
//models/budget.js
var Schema = require('jugglingdb').Schema;
var schema = new Schema('postgres',{url:process.env.DATABASE_URL});

var Budget = schema.define('budgets',{
  total: Number,
  slug: String
});

module.exports = Budget;
====================

//controllers/budget.js
function BudgetController (budget) {
  this.budget = budget;
};

BudgetController.prototype.DEFAULT_SLUG_LENGTH = 6;

BudgetController.prototype.generateSlug = function (req,res) {
  var slug = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  for (var i = 0; i < this.DEFAULT_SLUG_LENGTH; i++) {
    slug += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  res.send(slug);
};

module.exports = BudgetController;
===================

//app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

// models
var Budget = require('./models/budget');

// controllers
var BudgetController = require('./controllers/budget');
var budgetCtrl = new BudgetController(Budget);

// routes
app.get('/budgets',budgetCtrl.generateSlug);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4730);
```

If I manually instantiate the model/controller in the node repl, the generateSlug method works fine. If I restructure my code so that the BudgetController is a function that returns an object {} with methods, that seems to work fine. Is there some issue with my use of prototype/new ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

express takes functions and invokes them without a preceding object, so if you want to use an object method bound to a specific `this` as an express route handler function, you need to bind it:

```
app.get('/budgets', budgetCtrl.generateSlug.bind(budgetCtrl));
```